# Retrieving status code from ironRequest promise

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer, http-status-codes

When sending an ajax request using an `iron-ajax` element, I use the returned promise instead of specifying `on-response` and `on-error` methods, as it feels simpler.
However, when the request fails, the catch handler only contains an error object, with message like *"The request failed with status code: 403"*.

I would like to handle errors differently based on the status code, but parsing the error message seems awkward. Is there any other way to do so, or is this the way to go?

```
var p = elem.generateRequest().completes
p.catch (err) ->
  # How to retrieve http status code?
  # do smth
  return p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`<iron-ajax>.generateRequest()`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax#method-generateRequest) returns the corresponding `<iron-request>`, and you could get the status code from [`<iron-request>.status`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax?active=iron-request#property-status):

```
var req = this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
var p = req.completes;
p.catch(err => {
  console.log('err', err);
  console.log('statusText', req.statusText);
  console.log('status', req.status);
});
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(function() {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    ready: function() {
      var req = this.$.ajax.generateRequest();
      var p = req.completes;
      p.then(_ => console.log('done'))
       .catch(err => {
        console.log('err', err);
        console.log('statusText', req.statusText);
        console.log('status', req.status);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <iron-ajax id="ajax" url="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/postsx"></iron-ajax>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/begWbp?editors=1011)

Comment: This approach works only if the `catch` handler is in the same scope as the `generateRequest()` call. What can be done if the request is fired in a method that returns the promise, with a catch handler in a parent scope?